# trouble displaying sidebar text in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to add text to the sidebar of an r shiny app. I tried adding it as follows. I don't get any errors and the app runs as it did before but the text doesn't populate

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title of Plot"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("*Text I Am Trying To Add!!!!"),
                uiOutput("view"),
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
                uiOutput("studySelectUI"),
                downloadButton(outputId = "DataDownload", label = "Download Data")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
      plotlyOutput("Plot"),
      HTML("<br><br>"),
      dataTableOutput("Data")
  )
)
```

Comment: I figured it using an HTML tag as follows: HTML("<center> *Text I Am Trying to Add!!! </center>")

Comment: You can also do this by defining the string in the server section with a `output$textobject <- renderText({"Text I'm trying to add"})` call and then calling that output with the `VerbatimTextOutput` command. For your current use case, the HTML is of course fine, but the output object route would allow you to update the text on-the-fly if needed.